# React redux - update object state with new value

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I use Redux for the first time, and I don't success to update a state. Here is the workflow : User logged in the app (`/login`), a token is stored in sessionStorage, and I dispatch user info to access userData in the `/dashboard/:id` page.

Right now when I console.log props on the Dashboard components, here is the result :

```
userData : {}
```

So the object userData is still empty.
Here is the code :

LoginForm :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'; 
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import  * as authActions from '../../actions/authActions';


class LoginForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            errors: {},
            isLoading: false,
        };
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ errors: {}, isLoading: true });
        this.props.actions.logInUser( { data: { user: { email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password }}})
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
                    <div className="field">
                        <label className="label"> Email </label>
                        <div className="control">
                            <input type="email"
                                   name="email"
                                   value={this.state.email}
                                   onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
                                   className="input" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="field">
                        <label className="label"> Mot de passe </label>
                        <div className="control">
                        <input type="password"
                               ref="password"
                               name="password"
                               value={this.state.password}
                               onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
                               className="input" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Signup" className="button is-primary" />
                    </div>
                    <Link to={{ pathname: '/register' }}>Inscription</Link>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(authActions, dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginForm);
```

The authAction :

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import * as types from './types';
import sessionApi from '../api/SessionApi';

export function loginSuccess(userData) {
    return {
        type: types.LOG_IN_SUCCESS,
        payload: userData
    }
}

export function loginFailed() {
    return {
        type: types.LOG_IN_FAILED
    }
}

export function logInUser(credentials) {
    return function(dispatch) {
        return sessionApi.login(credentials)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                if(response.data) {
                    sessionStorage.setItem('jwt', response.data.authentication_token);
                    dispatch(loginSuccess(response.data));
                    browserHistory.push('/dashboard/' + response.data.id);
                } else {
                    dispatch(loginFailed());
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                throw(error);
            })
    }
}
```

The API :

```
import axios from 'axios';

class SessionApi {
    static login(credentials) {
        return axios.post('<link_hidden>', credentials)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            return error;
        });            
    }
}

export default SessionApi;
```

The session reducer (I have a rootReducer for combineReducer) :

```
import * as types from '../actions/types';
import initialState from './initialState';

export default function sessionReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case types.LOG_IN_SUCCESS:
        console.log(action);
            return {
                ...state,
                userData: action.payload
            }
        case types.LOG_IN_FAILED:
            console.log('login failed');
            break;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

and the initialState file :

```
export default {
    session: !!sessionStorage.jwt,
    userData: {}
}
```

Does someone know why the userData object is still empty ? In the session reducer I pass the userData so I don't understand ..

**EDIT**

```
dashboard.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Dashboard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(props);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1> Hello user </h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const userData = state.sessionReducer.userData;
    return { userData };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Dashboard);
```

Comment: Where do you experience the empty `userData`? Is it empty when you log it out in your reducer or in the axios call?

Comment: userData is empty when I log in Dashboard component, in the axios call it isn't empty it contain all data that I need

Comment: Could you include the Dashboard's code? Do you use mapStateToProps?

Comment: @MagicDragon just edited my question

Comment: How do you know it's not updating? Put a `console.log(this.props.userData)` in your render please and check it again.

Comment: @MagicDragon Yes it is, I've just console.log what you said and the result is `{}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156265/discussion-between-magicdragon-and-antonin-mrchd).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems fine to me. Could you check your router if it's working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try and change your userData to array, I think your payload may be an array of objects. That is:

```
export default {
session: !!sessionStorage.jwt,
userData:  [ ]
}
```